# PHP can't get $_SESSION["xxx"] value on another Page?

Tags: php, session

First Page :

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["username"]="skygao";
echo $_SESSION["username"];
```

after run this script on first page, O/P is:

```
skygao
```

Second Page :

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION["username"]);
```

I am trying to get value on second Page, but O/P is:

```
NULL
```

Can anyone help me?

> PHP5.4.45 + Nginx1.8 + CentOS6.5

php.ini session info:
[image]

Comment: Looks fine, are these pages on the same domain?

Comment: YES ,Two page same domain

Comment: can you share the urls of the two pages? how's you are calling them?

Comment: @james Do you have any subdomains?

Comment: is the save path writeable?